# How to get full log of packaged electron app error?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, yarn-workspaces

[image]

How can i know what node module is causing my packaged app to crash?the path is cut short.
Is there a way to get this error to terminal or file?

UPDATE:
i know the error comes from importing my workspace with yarn workspaces,
i commented this and packaged the app and works but i dont know whats wrong.it works when i just build it and run from terminal.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const { format } = require('url');
const { organizeFiles } = require('@movepics/script'); THIS ONE

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {...
```

Comment: hm, does it crash when it's not packaged. Can you just set a breakpoint and see what's going on?

Comment: it doesnt crash if i run from the terminal just "electron ./build/electron.js" works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was messing around with what i discovered and it seems cuz i have a exe file inside my package(yarn workspace) it causes this error, i just deleted the exe  and now it works.

Conclusion i have to learn how to make a package with prebuilt binaries inside or make the installer of electron download the binary.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have a console to display on in a production environment, you need to output the logs to a log file instead of a console. And then you can have an "upload logs" option (or just view it, if it's on your device not on a customer's device).

To do this use the "electron-log" npm package.

```js
const log = require('electron-log');
 
log.info('Hello, log');
log.warn('Some problem appears');
```

Caveat: Make sure you comply with the law regarding logs, as, mostly, logs have to be uploaded anonymously